# spring dev tools does not reload maven resources

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have some thymeleaf templates under maven src/main/resources/template path, when I change a controller java file, spring dev tools will trigger a restart, but when I change template files, the livereload does not work. At first, my maven had some problem building the project, it failed to add the files under src/main/resources to target/classes folder, then when I start the spring boot project(using spring tool suite), it showed a error that suggested templates not found. I rebuild the project use "mvn clean package" and restart the spring using spring dash board, it's OK. So I suspect that when I change the template file, it will not impact the target/classes folder, spring dev tools still get template from target/classes instead of detecting the changed file in src/main/resources/. Is there anything I miss to configure for spring dev tools?

Comment: I guess it's because spring dev tools or eclipse(sts) monitor target/classes instead of source code, unlike maven-jetty-plugin, you can configure using source code path, so that it can detect changes in all types of files. There's a workaround that I change the template file in target/classes,  it is working, but I don't think it's a good way to do stuff.

Comment: The problem is fixed, and I don't know why. I just build my project using the STS embedded maven(version 3.3.3) instead of my own maven. Maybe my maven version is old (version 3.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to reload maven dependencies in the following way: in Package Explorer right-click on a project folder and choose Maven -> Update Project (ALT+F5). It helped in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to auto reload Thymeleaf templates?
You may set `spring.thymeleaf.cache` property to `false`.

Reference: [72.2 Reload Thymeleaf templates without restarting the container](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-reload-thymeleaf-content)

Comment: "Cache options are usually configured by settings in your application.properties file. For example, Thymeleaf offers the spring.thymeleaf.cache property. Rather than needing to set these properties manually, the spring-boot-devtools module will automatically apply sensible development-time configuration."  the spring dev tools are setting cache to false automatically.